# Insert new column with data taken from other column + text

Tags: javascript, html

I am new here with very limited knowledge on programming.  I just use whatever I find from the web and expirement on them.  Let me explain how I meant.

I have a database text file that looks like this.

```
colh01|colh02|colh03|colh04|colh05|
data11|data12|data13|data14|data15|
data21|data22|data23|data24|data25|
data31|data32|data33|data34|data35|
data41|data42|data43|data44|data45|
```

Now I used the javascript I found in the web to display the contents to a table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function () {
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName)
        return;
    var frm = null, 
    prenode,
    tbod = document.getElementById('tbod'),
    data = '';
    if ((frm = top.frames['buffer']) //iframe
         && frm.document) { //get <pre> parent
        prenode = frm.document.getElementsByTagName('pre').item(0);
        if (null != prenode
             && null != prenode.firstChild
             && /#text/.test(prenode.firstChild.nodeName)) //text node
        {
            data += prenode.firstChild.data; //read
            data = data.split(/[\n\r]/); //separate lines
            data.splice(0, 0); //lose first two (legend)
            var i = 0,
            l = data.length, rowdata, ii, ll, tr, td;
            for (; i < l; ++i) {
                tr = document.createElement('tr'); //new row
                tbod.appendChild(tr);
                rowdata = data[i].split("|", 6); //separate bits
                for (ii = 0, ll = rowdata.length; ii < ll; ++ii) {
                    td = document.createElement('td'); //new cell
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowdata[ii]));
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

It works fine and the output looks like this.

```
colh01  colh02  colh03  colh04  colh05
data11  data12  data13  data14  data15
data21  data22  data23  data24  data25
data31  data32  data33  data34  data35
data41  data42  data43  data44  data45
```

Then I wanted to insert a column (colh6) that will have data taken from first column.  It should look like this

```
colh01  colh02  colh03  colh04  colh05  colh6 (new column)-->(link to file)
data11  data12  data13  data14  data15  'file-<data11>.pdf' -->(href='http://locahost/file-<data11>.pdf')
data21  data22  data23  data24  data25  'file-<data21>.pdf' -->(href='http://locahost/file-<data21>.pdf')
data31  data32  data33  data34  data35  'file-<data31>.pdf' -->(href='http://locahost/file-<data31>.pdf')
data41  data42  data43  data44  data45  'file-<data41>.pdf' -->(href='http://locahost/file-<data41>.pdf')
```

How do I go about this? The data is a hyperlink that user can click to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've completed the hard part, all you're missing is how to create a link using Javascript.  If you just add these lines after your loop, it will create a link using the content of the first column;

```
var newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost/file-' + rowdata[0] + '.pdf');
newlink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Link text'));
td = document.createElement('td');
td.appendChild(newlink);
tr.appendChild(td);
```

More info on creating dynamic links [here](http://technage.blogspot.se/2009/02/dynamically-adding-anchor-tag-with.html).

Comment: You are appending an `a` tag to a `TR` ?

Comment: Hi Joachim, where in the script should I put this.  Thanks for your prompt help

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify this bit to display the links:

```
for (; i < l; ++i)
{
    tr = document.createElement('tr'); //new row
    tbod.appendChild(tr);
    rowdata = data[i].split("|",6); //separate bits
    for (ii = 0, ll = rowdata.length; ii < ll; ++ii)
    {
        td = document.createElement('td'); //new cell
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowdata[ii]));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    td = document.createElement('td') //column 6 cell
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<a href="http://locahost/file-' + rowdata[0] + '.pdf"> Link text here </a>'));
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

Comment: Where is the "hyperlink that user can click to open the file" ?

Comment: lol.. missed the tag itself looking at the example above.. edited now.. thanks for the review :)

Comment: Hi Ritik Khatwani, thanks!!! its working as expected.  I may have missed out something, I have amended my post.

Comment: Ritik Khatwani, I have just started here I cannot flag your answer as helpful.  Low reputation.  But you help me get started.  Thanks so much!